# I couldn't able to run my MVC.net project in my Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, drupal-8, iis-express

Whenever i try to run my any .net project from mine Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017. It is suddenly stop and throw me an error.`The program '[191420] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`"

**In Browser:**
[Click here to see an error occur in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE1fd.png)

**In VS 2017:**
[Click here to see an error occur in VS 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uanoy.png)

**Note:**

After Drupal 8 setup in to my pc, I start getting this error.

I am happy to see the reply on this issue.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9cbe05df-36df-4005-857f-d08ac82492b3/the-program-14400-iisexpressexe-has-exited-with-code-0-0x0?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Several method below might be helpful:

1) Check your solution folder for a hidden ".vs" folder with a "config" sub-folder. If that folder exists and it has it's own `applicationhost.confi`g file you need to either rename (or delete) that file or edit it and make sure the website(s) configured inside match the ASP.NET web app(s) in your solution that you are trying to debug. Hope this helps.

2) Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, right click on the web project, chose properties and then navigated to the "web" tab. From there I changed the Project URL to another port number. 
For example, if it was http://localhost:1052 - I changed it to  http://localhost:4356.
[image]

3)

If your machine is 64bit, please go to Tools-> options -> projects and solutions:
[image]

Please let me know which one shown above could help.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn Xiao for your reply but it is not working for me.